# terminal command that prints out tabs, spaces, and newlines as \t \s and \n

Tags: text-processing, whitespace

I wrote a terminal program in c that converts tabs to spaces. And I would like to see that it works and how many spaces were converted from tabs. The problem is when I create a file called input.txt and pipe it to the program, it just shows blanks for both tabs and spaces rather than the actual characters \t and \s. So I am wondering if there is an existing terminal command that could take the output of my program and replace tabs and spaces with \t and \s respectively:

```
cat input7.txt | ./detab
abc  def
```

Perhaps something like:

```
cat input7.txt | ./detab | command
abc\s\s\sdef\s\s\s
```

Does such a command exist already?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under Linux, `cat -T` shows tabs as `^I`. There are other options to make trailing whitespace apparent, to display control characters in a printable form, etc.

If you want to compare the result of your program with the original, you can use `diff`:

```
./detab input7.txt | diff input7.txt - | cat -T
```

You may also want to compare the input of your program with the standard utility `expand`.

If you want exactly the transformation of spaces into `\s` and tabs into `\t`, you can use sed:

```
sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' -e 's/\t/\\t/g' -e 's/ /\\s/g'
```

(The first expression doubles backslashes, which makes the transformation unambiguous.)